# delete all rules from iptables

Tags: sh, firewall, iptables

I'm make a shell script have some rules to limit connection on port
Then it's effect badly on my vps

Script :

```
#!/bin/bash
# Window of time in seconds
SECS=60
# Max connections per IP
MAXCONN=5
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 5222 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 5222 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds ${SECS} --hitcount ${MAXCONN} -j REJECT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 5223 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 5223 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds ${SECS} --hitcount ${MAXCONN} -j REJECT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 5224 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 5224 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds ${SECS} --hitcount ${MAXCONN} -j REJECT
```

And I need to remove all this rules

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried my answer, if it works please select the answer.

Comment: @JerryZhang how can I know if it's work? how can I see all the rules ??

Comment: i updated the answer, you can get it from another command.

Answer (score 0):

To run this command to flush all the rules:

```
iptables -F
```

This command will print all the rules:

```
iptables -L -n -v
```

Following command is to save firewall change

```
service iptables save
```